# Getting Cell Width of Matplotlib Table to Cover Text and Surrounding Figure

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have been beating my head up over this for the last few hours so any help would be greatly appreciated. I have a table of a certain dimensionality, with each cell containing a certain phrase. Each cell also has an associated float value (normalized to 1) that is being colored using a CMAP. However, I am having trouble getting the table (and cells) to cover the full width of the enclosing figure. Here is the non-functional code I've been using:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(6,3))



diff = kb_weights.max() - kb_weights.min()
normal = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(kb_weights.min() - diff / 2.0, kb_weights.max() + diff / 2.0)
ax.axis("off")
img = plt.imshow(kb_weights, cmap="Blues")
plt.colorbar()
img.set_visible(False)

table = ax.table(cellText=kb_realized[0:10, :], colLabels=kb_cols_realized,

# The dimensionality of the table is 10x6                                      cellColours=plt.cm.Blues(normal(kb_weights[:10, :])),
                                 loc="center", fontsize=10)

table.auto_set_font_size(False)
table.scale(1.5,1.5)
ax.add_table(table)
plt.savefig("../figures/kb_weights.png")
```

And here is what the resulting image looks like: [image]

Completely incomprehensible, I know, but I'm really unsure as to how to get matplotlib to do what i want it to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `bbox` parameter of the `table` to specify how much of the plot it spans. For example:

```
table = ax.table(cellText=..., bbox=(0, 0, 1, 1))
```

Will make it fill the entire axes `ax`. You will have to adjust it so that it spans the part of the plot that you want it to.

The `bbox` tuple gives `(x0, y0, width, height)`. Lower left corner is `(0, 0)`, and upper right corner is `(1, 1)`.

Comment: How do you change the width of the bbox after made?